# Invest on etf when you are young

Tags: investing, etf

I started to work a year ago and I'm putting all my savings in one ETF (SCHD), to have a lot of dividends when I'll turn 60 and then retire.
Is that a good solution, given the fact that I'm still young and I should probably put my money in more risky investments?
I read that SCHD can be nice when you don't want to take risks, but the growth isn't that great compared to other options I could invest in.
What's your mind about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investing early is great. Compound returns do amazing things when given more years to work with.

I haven't looked at that particular fund, but the keyword I'd hit you with is **diversify"*. At the very least you want a wide mix of stocks and a wide mix of bonds.

The traditional "I don't want to think about it" advice is that at age N, having N% in a "total bond market" fund and (100-N)% in a "total stock market" fund is a decent basic starting point. You have a long time before you need the money, in which any downturns can recover, so you can afford higher risk than most of us to get higher average gain, but mixing stocks and bonds is generally a good safety net.

Later you can fine-tune this among kinds of stocks and add international stocks and REITs to the mix, and consider whether you're interested enough to set aside a small amount to actively invest -- see lots of other answers here -- but that'll get you started in the right direction with minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

Dividends are not "income" or "growth" in the sense that they are just pulling cash from the ETF. The value of the ETF goes does by the amount of the dividend for that reason.  Stocks that pay high dividends tend to be mature companies that are safe but may not have the growth potential of younger companies.

Even though you're looking decades down the line, don't focus too much on dividends now. Yes they are a handy way to get cash from your investments without selling them, but certainly while you're young you should focus more on growth that dividends.  If you focus on higher growth, that growth will compound much more than you'll ever get in dividends.  You can always shift to dividends when you actually retire if you want to simplify the withdrawals.

This is not specific financial advice, just something to consider.

Comment: The problem with that equivalence is that emphasizing stock price over (re-investable) dividends creates some perverse incentives for upper management. Unfortunately that's what many shareholders are currently demanding.

Comment: Don't dividends create improper incentives too? For example, managers may not take advantage of investment opportunities if they know that they need cash to pay dividends?  Not saying you're wrong, just not sure that dividends should be the main goal over share price.